# How to group by specifying a function to fetch a key?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have web application errors reported to mongo db. To fetch them (grouped by URLs) I use the following query:

```
db.errors.group({
    cond: {
        date:{
            $gt:new Date(2013,0,3, 6, 0, 0), 
            $lt:new Date(2013,0,3, 8, 0, 0)
        }
    },
    key: {
        url: 1
    },
    initial: {
        csum: 0
    },
    reduce:
        function(obj, prev) {
            prev.csum++;
        }
})
```

What should I do if I would like to count the errors by a **site url** (as opposed to a *page* url)? I mean, that *http://www.mysite.com/page1* and *http://www.mysite.com/page2* will be counted in the same bucket. Ideally, it would be a function in the `key` section of the query somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend JohnnyHK's answer:

```
db.errors.group({
    cond: {
        date:{
            $gt:new Date(2013,0,3, 6, 0, 0),
            $lt:new Date(2013,0,3, 8, 0, 0)
        }
    },
    keyf: function(doc)
    {
        return { site: doc.url.match(/.*:\/\/[^\/]+/i)[0]};
    },
    initial: {
        csum: 0
    },
    reduce:
        function(obj, prev) {
            prev.csum++;
        }
})
```

Returns:

```
[
    {
        "site" : "http://www.mysite.com",
        "csum" : 3
    },
    {
        "site" : "http://www.example.com",
        "csum" : 1
    }
]
```

With a large dataset it's not going to be fast though. If you control the code that generates the errors it might be easier to add a `domain` field you could group on.

Comment: thanks! will the code work only for `*.com` sites (as opposed to `.net` etc)?

Comment: Adjust the regex to fit your needs. I've edited my example to match every tld.

Comment: Accepting the answer, though `doc.url.split('/')[2]` worked well for my needs :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `keyf` instead of `key` in your `group` to specify a function that creates the site url key you require rather than relying on an existing document field.

See the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/).

Comment: a code snippet would help: the doc is not very transparent about the `key object` that should be returned from the `keyf` function, also it would be good to have an advice on how to get the site name from the URL (optional).

Comment: Looks like Justin added an example.  Writing a robust function to return just the site portion of the page URLs is going to be tricky if you want it to handle all possible cases.  I was hoping that in your use case you could bound it to what you expect which would simplify things.