# How to fetch a site name from URL in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, serverside-javascript

Is there an easy way to fetch a site name from a URL string?

Example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/mypath/mypage -> www.mysite.com
http://mysite.com/mypath/mypage     -> mysite.com
```

The JS code is executed on mongodb CLI side, **not** in a browser.

Comment: Can I ask, why is this being executed in the MongoDB CLI? Would it not be more prudent to do this on document insert in node.js? Or on querying it?

Comment: It's a part of a `group` query in MongoDB.

Comment: Can you show us what you have for this group query atm? It sounds good doing it this way, more that if you were querying (grouping) on the site name often you would want to save the document with the site name pre-regexed out since even though you can, in the aggregation framework, regex out parts it could never use an index which would be dirt slow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182973/how-to-group-by-specifying-a-function-to-fetch-a-key - please see the marked answer (and my comment under it)

Comment: that group is old and slow plus it won't work on sharded collections and takes full read lock from other operations while running ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/commands/#group ) but yea I see your not using that regex as a condition which should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked well for me:

urlString.split('/')[2]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
url.href = "http://www.mysite.com/mypath/mypag";

url.protocol; // => "http:"
url.hostname; // => "example.com" // site name, you want
```

The `window.document.location.href` has the url of the page, and the `window.document.location.hostname` will have the sitename.

So,

```
console.log(window.document.location.hostname); // will log the sitename in the console
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy.

```
window.location.hostname; //Domain name

$("title").text(); //Page name
```

and this too

```
var loc = window.location;

var filename = loc.pathname.split("/");
filename = filename[pathname.length-1];

alert("Domain: "+loc.hostname);
alert("Filename: "+filename);
```

Comment: aha.....well i am sorry when i saw your post it did not mentioned the cli thing ..let me see....for mongo

Comment: actually, its not my post :)

Comment: the second option pushed me well to the correct answer :) keep the upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can abuse an anchor in order to get your desired data out of an URL. :D

```
function getDomain(url) {
  var anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.setAttribute('href', url);

  return anchor.hostname;
}

console.log(getDomain('http://www.mysite.com/mypath/mypage'));
console.log(getDomain('http://mysite.com/mypath/mypage'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Js76M/

Comment: the question is about server-side JS (mongodb/node.js etc) - my question was edited by someone else, rolled back

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sitename = new URL(site_url)?.hostname?.replace("www.", "")
console.log(sitename)
```

Answer (score -1):

I also need to get domain from a url to show only domain name on a reference section of my app.

I found this here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

> The URL() constructor returns a newly created URL object representing
> the URL defined by the parameters.
>
> If the given base URL or the resulting URL are not valid URLs, the
> JavaScript TypeError exception is thrown.

```
function getDomain(url) {
   return new window.URL(url).hostname;
}
```

new URl(url) returns an object with the follows properties

```
hash: ""
host: "developer.mozilla.org"
hostname: "developer.mozilla.org"
href: "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL"
origin: "https://developer.mozilla.org"
password: ""
pathname: "/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL"
port: ""
protocol: "https:"
search: ""
```