# How to specify a key function for group aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to aggregate by `UserAgent`:

```
db.reports.aggregate(
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$UserAgent',
            docsPerUserAgent: {
                $sum : 1
            }
        }
    }
)
```

The query above will take into account the **entire** `UserAgent` string. What I would like to do, is to count those that contain *Android* (option A), *iPhone/iPad* (option B) and the rest (option C). How can I supply the `keyf` function to the aggregation framework (something similar to this - [How to group by specifying a function to fetch a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182973/how-to-group-by-specifying-a-function-to-fetch-a-key) but in the context of an aggregation framework)?

Comment: Currently there is no projection for taking a piece of a string to group on except for substr which will not do what your looking for. Normally the best way to do this is to store the user agent in the pieces you need to group on

Comment: if so, why not share it as an answer (I'll approve it)?

Comment: if you provided an example document it might help suggest a different way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: `UserAgent` is a field that might contain *Android*, *iPhone*/*iPad*, etc. I would like to `group by` using that projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is nothing that allows you to do somehting like:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$project: {userAgentType: {$extract: /(Android|iPhone/iPad)/}}},
    {$group: on_userAgentType}
]);
```

Maybe this feature exists in the JIRA already however, I couldn't immediately find it.

Instead on of the better ways to do this would be to split the "interesting" parts of the user agent string out into separate fields so you can group by something like `userAgent.agentType` which represents either `android` or `ipad` or `iphone`. Not only that but you can also use this to produce a `$match` before hand which should mean you can use an index on this field making your aggregation a lot more performant in general.

Comment: just one question: what was the `substr` you mentioned in the comments?

Comment: @BreakPhreak http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_substr allows you to basically do the same as what `substr` does in most languages like PHP whereby you can split a field of a document by skipping, say for example, the first character of the value and stopping 3 characters later, i.e. in PHP `substr('hello world', 1, 3)` would return `ello`

Comment: updated link for the substr function docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/